# Ajax contact form within one-page HTML5 design not functioning

Tags: php, html, contact-form, ajaxform

I purchased a web template but there is no post-purchase support.  It is a one-page HTML5 design.  The menu buttons link to page anchors within the index.html (page_ABOUT, page_SERVICES, etc).  The site is designed so that the linked page anchors slide smoothly into place between static z-indexed images.  A working demo of the template [CAN BE SEEN HERE](http://www.dynamic-template.com/template/preview/85528).

My issue involves the about_CONTACTS page anchor.  I have other contact pages on other sites that work well, but those are PHP pages (i.e., contact.php).  In order to stay within the confines of this design, I need to be able to make the about_CONTACTS page function within the single HTML page. (Opting to create a separate PHP contact page breaks the design's slide function and causes a page reload.) The block of code for the about_CONTACTS page form is:

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
<div class="clear"></div>
<label>Your full name:</label>
<INPUT class="textbox left " type="text" name="name" value="">
<div class="clear"></div>
<label >E-Mail:</label>
<INPUT class="textbox left" type="text" name="email" value="">
<div class="clear"></div>
<label >Phone Number:</label>
<INPUT class="textbox left" type="text" name="phone" value="">
<div class="clear"></div>
<label >Message:</label>
<TEXTAREA class="textbox left" NAME="content" ROWS="5" COLS="25"></TEXTAREA>
<div class="clear"></div>
<label>Captcha:</label>
<img src="captcha/captcha.php" style="margin:3px 0px; width:100px; height:32px; float:left;">
<INPUT class="textbox" type="text" name="capthca" value="" style=" width:90px; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:2px">
<div class="clear"></div>
<INPUT class="pin" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The JavaScript between the head tags is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                     
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() { 
    var str = $(this).serialize();      
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "contact.php", 
      data: str, 
      success: function(msg)
      { 
        if(msg == 'OK') // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
        { 
          result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!<br> <a href="#" onclick="freset();return false;">send another mail</a></div>'; $("#fields").hide(); 
        }
        else { 
          result = msg; 
        } 
        $("#note").html(result); 
      } 
    }); 
    return false; 
   }); 
});

function freset()
{   
  $("#note").html('');  
  document.getElementById('ajax-contact-form').reset();
  $("#fields").show();
}

</script>
```

The form calls for contact.php, the contents of which [CAN BE SEEN HERE](http://yipcabbage.com/01/contact.php.txt).  Contact.php calls for the inclusions of contact_config.php (contents of file [CAN BE SEEN HERE](http://yipcabbage.com/01/contact_config.php.txt)) and functions.php (contents [CAN BE SEEN HERE](http://yipcabbage.com/01/functions.php.txt)).

I placed the intended send/receive email address in contact_config.php:

```
<?php
// To
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'email@companyname.com');
?>
```

As so:

```
<?php
// To
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'me@mydomain.com');
?>
```

Would you please advise why the submit button does not respond to a click and why no mail is being sent?  I've never used this type of form before and while I'm sure I'm meant to edit something else, I'm at a loss as to what and where to edit. (I have taken great care to be sure that captchas are entered correctly.  I am receiving neither error messages nor success messages.  There is no response at all, when attempting to submit a message via the contact form.)

Comment: "doesn't respond to a click" are you sure? It looks like it should. Have you put in a console.log() call to see if the "submit" handler is executing? Have you checked the browser console to see if there are any errors? You're not handling the "error" callback of the $.ajax() method, so if there are any HTTP errors from the call you won't see them in the app (but you might in the console).

Comment: @ADyson  I've cleared the console logs and have gone through the motions again, but  I'm getting nothing but one issue regarding the favicon (and that was only in Firefox; there is nothing in Chrome).  I did try, this time, deliberately entering the wrong captcha and I did get an error message stating that it was wrong.  However, when entering all the information correctly and clicking Submit, there is no action at all.  Nothing is arriving in the inbox.  I'm sorry; I do not know how to put in a console.log() call.

Comment: console.log is a just a javascript command that will write output to the browser's console. So you could do something like this: `$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() { console.log("entered the submit handler"); //etc `

Comment: also what about in the browser's network tab? can you see if the ajax call results in a HTTP 200 (OK) response, or some other status code?

Comment: also I've just noticed, your form is not sending data to anywhere `<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');">` - the "action" attribute is completely wrong. It should be something like `action="contact.php"`. Otherwise it doesn't know where to send the form to. And also you'll need the `method="POST"` attribute as well, otherwise it'll default to GET and your PHP won't pick up the variables

Comment: I've made the changes:  action="contact.php" and method="POST".  Several odd things are happening.  I am now getting an incorrect captcha error, regardless.  (The captcha is easy to read and easy to check for accuracy before submitting.)  In addition, I'm getting this in the console: SyntaxError: missing } after function body  and it is referring to this line:  {  $("#note").html('');  document.getElementById('ajax-contact-form').reset();  $("#fields").show();}  I am also getting a status 304 "not modified" on submit.png.

Comment: (The incorrect captcha error is only happening since changing the action to "contact.php")

Comment: the 304 on the .png doesn't matter - it just means it was able to use a cached version of the image. I was more thinking you should monitor the response from the call to contact.php, after you click submit. The script as per your sample doesn't generate a syntax error for me if I put it into a page on its own. Have you modified it since then, or got some other script in the page?

Comment: re the captcha error, have you checked that $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] is being set to the correct value (it's not clear where this happens - in "captcha.php" maybe?

Comment: The way it's set up presently, is that the JavaScript in the head tags looks exactly as it does in my opening post, with the exception that this is the first line:  $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() { console.log("entered the submit handler");   The first line in the form's HTML is <form id="ajax-contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">  I am still getting the incorrect captcha error but I'm now getting this (too long for this comment) in the console:

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.   (Seems to be referencing contact.php)  index.html contains <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: captcha.php is as follows:  include('captcha-gen.php');
session_start();
$captcha = new captcha();
$_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] = $captcha->getKeyString();

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK 377ms

Comment: ok so it is displaying the message returned in "msg" with no problem, by the sounds of it. So your only issue now is the captcha? You probably need to echo out the values of $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] and $_POST["capthca"] at the point where you're comparing them in contact.php and check the values are what you're expecting.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to echo out the values (or what that means) but I'm willing to spend some time researching it so that I don't continue to take your time.  May I ask, though; does it matter that the template designer used $_POST["capthca"] instead of $_POST["captcha"] in contact.php?  I edited it to be "captcha" but should I not have done that?

Comment: to echo, use the "echo" command :-). See where in contact.php you've got  `echo 'OK';`? Well use the same command to output the value of your other variables. As for the POST var...whatever you call it must match what is in the "name" attribute of the HTML element you're trying to read. So if you have `<INPUT class="textbox" type="text" name="capthca"/>` in your HTML then you need to have `$_POST["capthca"]` in your PHP in order to see the value. Likewise if you have `<input type="text name="myVariable">` in HTML then you'd need `$_POST["myVariable"]` in PHP. They have to match, that's all.

Comment: It was captcha in the HTML file, so I left my edit. :)   Do I place the echo within this string (and do I need an "if" statement):  if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) && strtolower($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) != strtolower($_POST['captcha']))
{
$error .= "Incorrect captcha.<br />";
}

Comment: @ADyson would you put your advice to echo out the values of $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] and $_POST["capthca"]  in the form of an answer so that I can mark it with a check as the solution?  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the solution is along the following lines:

a) change your form tag from

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
```

to

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
```

Your version is invalid - the action should specify where the form sends its data to, and the method is required in order to force a postback (otherwise it uses GET by default, which your PHP is not set up to deal with (you are reading `$_POST` variables).

b) check the values of  `$_SESSION['captcha_keystring']` and `$_POST["capthca"]` to make sure they really contain what you think they do. e.g

e.g. (just for the purposes of debugging - don't leave this in for production use!):

```
$error .= "Captcha keystring: ".strtolower($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']);
$error .= " User-entered captcha: ".strtolower($_POST['capthca']);

if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) && strtolower($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) != strtolower($_POST['capthca']))
{
  $error .= "Incorect captcha.<br />";
}
```

Also make sure that your HTML captcha textbox has the correct name attribute (`name="capthca"`) to match your PHP `$_POST["capthca"]`.